# Why does my CGI::Session keep emptying itself randomly?

Tags: perl, cgi, session

The session loads fine for the most part but it is randomly clearing all of the data some times and I don't know why:

Create my new session:

```
$session = CGI::Session->new( "driver:file",undef,{Directory => '/tmp'} );

$session->param('logged_in', 1);
$session->expire('logged_in', '+10m');

$session->expire('+1h');
```

Now when I go to another page and load the session I do:

```
$session = CGI::Session->load ( "driver:file", $sid, {Directory => '/tmp'} );

return 0 if $session->is_expired;

return 0 if !$session->param('logged_in');

return $session;
```

The problem I have is that sometimes, before the 10 minute mark is up the 'logged_in' param is empty when it should not be. Why could this be happening?

Comment: @user105033 So, are you still observing the issue with `->new` and `->load` or are you not? Your edit makes my response look nonsensical. Which version of the code are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you do not seem to be using [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html): You should. Second, don't use indirect object notation. I.e., use `CGI::Session->new`.

To find out what is going on, use the sequential id generator for debugging and make sure you are looking at the session you think you are looking at. Make sure you create the session on log on, but from that point on, you `load` it.

Check how you are keeping track of the session id: Are you using cookies, query string parameters or from parameters? Make sure the correct session id is available at all times.

Comment: I pass the correct SID through query string, the same thing is happening even if I use load. When using load, i check is_empty and it is randomly empty. Could my host have a time limit on how long files can exist in the /tmp directory?

Comment: hmmm seems to be working now that switched from indirect object notation... not sure why though, i'll keep an eye out fora  little.

Comment: @user105033 If not using indirect object notation solved your problem for sure, then one of the gotchas listed in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax is responsible. Possibly, `new` was being called as a subroutine and not a method.